# Use LINQ GroupBy with SPListItemsCollection

Tags: development, linq, grouping

I have a SharePoint list containing some items. I would like to apply grouping to the items using LINQ, preferably with `.GroupBy` method.

This is the list of fields that the list item is consisted of:

- **Title** - Single line of text field
- **Date** - Date and time field
- **Related** - Lookup field

I need to have the items collection grouped by the `Related` lookup field. I am unable to figure out what to specify for `GroupBy` method parameters. The following code throws an error and prevents it being built.

```
var items = list.Items;
var groupedItems = items.Cast<SPListItem>().
    GroupBy(item => new SPFieldLookupValue(item["Related"].ToString()).LookupId);
```

Replacing LINQ with `<GroupBy>` element in list item query is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you want to group by the LookupId, so you could do something like this:

```
var items = list.Items;
var groupedItems = items.OfType<SPListItem>().GroupBy(item => new SPFieldLookupValue(item["Related"]).LookupId);
```

The mistake should be you have converted the `Object` to `string`, then converting it to `SPFieldLookupValue` and trying to get `LookupId` from it. Instead do convert the `Object` directly to `SPFieldLookupValue`.